# ANTLR parse key value list

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm new to ANTLR and I am trying to parse something like

ref:something title:(something else) blah ref other

and to obtain a list like

1. KEY = ref  VALUE = something
2. KEY = title VALUE = something else
3. KEY = null VALUE = blah
4. KEY = null VALUE = ref  // same ref string as item 1 key
5. KEY = null VALUE = other

The grammar I have is

```
searchCriteriaList 
    locals[List<object> s = new List<object>()]
           : t+=criteriaBean (WS t+=criteriaBean)* { $s.addAll($t); }
           ;

criteriaBean : (KEY ':' WS* expression)
             | expression ;

expression  : '(' WORD (WS WORD)* ')'
            | WORD ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

fragment A  : ('A'|'a') ;
fragment B  : ('B'|'b') ;
fragment C  : ('C'|'c') ;
fragment D  : ('D'|'d') ;
fragment E  : ('E'|'e') ;
fragment F  : ('F'|'f') ;
fragment G  : ('G'|'g') ;
fragment H  : ('H'|'h') ;
fragment I  : ('I'|'i') ;
fragment J  : ('J'|'j') ;
fragment K  : ('K'|'k') ;
fragment L  : ('L'|'l') ;
fragment M  : ('M'|'m') ;
fragment N  : ('N'|'n') ;
fragment O  : ('O'|'o') ;
fragment P  : ('P'|'p') ;
fragment Q  : ('Q'|'q') ;
fragment R  : ('R'|'r') ;
fragment S  : ('S'|'s') ;
fragment T  : ('T'|'t') ;
fragment U  : ('U'|'u') ;
fragment V  : ('V'|'v') ;
fragment W  : ('W'|'w') ;
fragment X  : ('X'|'x') ;
fragment Y  : ('Y'|'y') ;
fragment Z  : ('Z'|'z') ;


fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;

TITLE   : T I T L E ;
MESSAGE : M E S S A G E ;
REF     : R E F ;

KEY     : TITLE | MESSAGE | REF ;
WORD    : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | '_')+ ;
WS      : [ \t\u000C\r\n] ;
```

When I try parsing the string I get 2 exceptions and in the addAll method I end up with 3 elements rather than 5.
Can someone point me into the right direction? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
S

PS: The exception I am getting is:

```
Exception of type 'Antlr4.Runtime.InputMismatchException' was thrown.
InputStream: {ref:something title:(something else) blah ref other }
OffendingToken: {[@0,0:2='ref',<5>,1:0]}
```

Comment: Can you post the exceptions? Also, try stepping through your program with a debugger.

Comment: updated posting with Exception details
Exception of type 'Antlr4.Runtime.InputMismatchException' was thrown.
InputStream: {ref:something title:(something else) blah ref other }
OffendingToken: {[@0,0:2='ref',<5>,1:0]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lexer tries to match as much characters as possible when constructing tokens. When 2 or more lexer rules match the same characters, the rule defined first "wins". With this in mind, the `KEY` token will never be created since `TITLE`, `MESSAGE` and `REF` are defined above it:

```
TITLE   : T I T L E ;
MESSAGE : M E S S A G E ;
REF     : R E F ;

KEY     : TITLE | MESSAGE | REF ;
WORD    : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | '_')+ ;
```

So the input `ref` will **always** become a `REF` token, **never** a `KEY` or a `WORD`. What you need to do is create a parser rule from `KEY` instead.

Also, since you want a `WORD` to also match your keywords, you should not do this:

```
expression
 : '(' WORD (WS WORD)* ')'
 | WORD 
 ;
```

but something like this instead:

```
expression
 : '(' word (WS word)* ')'
 | word 
 ;

word
 : key
 | WORD
 ;

key
 : TITLE
 | MESSAGE
 | REF
 ;
```

Oh, and this:

```
fragment Z  : ('Z'|'z') ;
```

can be rewritten as:

```
fragment Z  : [Zz] ;
```

And is there a particular reason you're littering your parser rules with `WS` tokens? You could just remove them during tokenisation:

```
WS      : [ \t\u000C\r\n] -> skip;
```